# bootstrap 3: button as dropdown action

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could you help me stylize buttons to look like a standard dropdown link?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>

    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <form>
                <button class="btn btn-link">Dropdown Button</a>
            </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imbolc/YHvFF/)

Comment: What do you want? A dropdown within a dropdown?

Comment: A form within dropdown.

Comment: Can you please be clear? You want your button to look like a standard dropdown link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu form button {
    border:0;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    color: #333;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}
.dropdown-menu form button:hover {
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
```

It will look like a standard link.